# What do these operators do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, vb.net, url

I'm working within an MVC and need to change the blog url from being `/about/blog` to just `/blog`... easier said than done haha.

I'm wading through the controllers and various other .vb files to try and solve this and have come across the URL routing system.

What is the difference between the following (ignore the naming for now)

```
    ' Route 1
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "legal", _
        "{action}",
        New With {.controller = "home", .action = "index"},
        New With {.action = "^(terms|privacy|cookies|responsiblegaming|disclaimer|legal|acceptableuse)$"},
        New String() {"ProjectMVC"}
    )
```

and

```
    ' Route 2
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "legal", _
        "{action}",
        New With {.controller = "home", .action = "index"},
        New With {.action = "^[a-zA-Z_]+$", .slug = "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-\|]*$"},
        New String() {"ProjectMVC"}
    )
```

I think what I'm most confused about is knowing what it is looking for and doing, ie - what does this mean `"^[a-zA-Z_]+$"` and this  `"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-\|]*$"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking at are route constraints. Basically, you use constraints (in your case these are regular expression constraints) to tell routing system under which conditions can these routes be called.

The first RegEx value, `^[a-zA-Z_]+$` means "An action can start and end with any character defined between the brackets. These can only by small letters *a* to *z*, capital letters *A* to *Z*, and an underscore charater. Repeated one or more times."

To be more technically precise "Any character defined in the given class [a-zA-Z_] one or more times."

The other value is `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-\|]*$` means "A slug must start and end with a letter *a* to *z* or capital letter *A* to *Z*, after that it can have zero or more characters that are in range *a* to *z* or *A* to *Z*, or number between 0 and 9, or underscore, dash or pipe".

And that's about it. You might want to learn more about Regular Expression. Check this site
[Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Awesome, that's pretty clear. So the `controller` is used to define which controller to use?

Comment: Yes. I wrote an article about routing, so you might want to check it here: http://mvcdeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/routing-in-mvc-part-1/ Although this is in C# you can still get a picture even if you are a VB programmer.

Comment: That definitely helps, so atm the blog displays at `/blog/blog`, it was at `/about/blog/`. I've moved the file into the correct 'view' folder and migrated the actions from the about controller to the blog controller. Will defining the controller in the code above as `""` remove the first 'blog'?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean? What do you mean by "Will defining the controller in the code above as "" remove the first 'blog'?" Which part do you refer to as `""`?

Comment: Well at the moment, the blog URL is `/blog/blog` but obviously that's pretty bad, it should just be `/blog`. So can the {controller} (or {action}) part be removed from the URL?

Comment: From the above route definitions I cannot see that this is the case. It could be that you have area called **blog** defined or the virtual folder in IIS is set to **blog**.